# Date parse issue with CANADA country/locale and MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a date

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am currently parsing date with below code

```
   Date outDate = null;
   SimpleDateFormat formatter = null;
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat,locale);
   outDate = formatter.parse(dt);
```

I am aware its old way of parsing date. The problem i am facing is that the above code is not working once i use CANADA country/locale.
Below is the date and format -

> date - 02/05/2021 01:17 PM   format - MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a   locale -
> en_CA

The code works for all the format and countries but only once i use CANADA locale and format (MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a),  i don't get output date.

Comment: what message (exception) did you receive?

Comment: no error, formatter.parse(dt) retruns null

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the latter in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I get `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "02/05/2021 01:17 PM"`. That is, I cannot reproduce the `null` value that you reported.

Comment: @OleV.V. not sure why you get it. The code seems to work for me with other locale and date

Comment: Sun, Oracle, and the JCP years ago gave up on the `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes with the unanimous adoption of JSR 310 define the *java.time*. So should you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time

I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for you date and time work. Also it turns out that Canadian English uses *a.m.* and *p.m.* rather than *AM* and *PM* as in your input.

If you want to accept `AM` and `PM` in uppercase without dots — well, Canadian English doesn’t do that (at least not in the Java versions that you and I have tried). Therefore use for example `Locale.ENGLISH`. Define a formatter like this:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Now parsing is a one-liner:

```
    String dt = "02/05/2021 01:17 PM";
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dt, FORMATTER);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

And output is:

> 2021-02-05T13:17

If instead you want to use Canadian English locale, you must fit your input string to it. Let’s first modify the formatter to the desired locale:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", Locale.CANADA);
```

To learn how the locale expects the date to be written, let’s first format some date and time using the formatter:

```
    System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now(
            ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(FORMATTER));
```

> 06/08/2021 08:28 p.m.

Ah — so `p.m.` (and I bet `a.m.` too) with lower case letters and dots. We can do that:

```
    String dt = "02/05/2021 01:17 p.m.";
```

Now it parses just fine:

> 2021-02-05T13:17

Caveat: the strings used for AM and PM in Canadian locale may vary by Java version, I have not checked.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: I suggest a summary sentence up top saying “Canadian English formatting uses x but your input is y.”.

Answer (score 2):

The right format for locale `new Locale("en","CA")` is:

```
"02/05/2021 01:17 p.m."
```

Just change `PM` to `p.m.` in the input date (`dt` in your case).
Another solution could be changing the `dateFormat`, or remove locale from `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: The above code seems to work for me and with other locales.

Comment: @NarendraPandey It will work with any locale that spells AM/PM the same way as the input string. Your input string has `AM` and `PM`, in uppercase without punctuation, so you need a locale that has that, e.g. `en-US`.